# TCP read write issue .net

Tags: .net, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am using the below code which sends the message from a specific server

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    send("Hello there")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "Send Successful"
End Sub

Public Sub send(ByVal data As String)
    Dim tcpClient As New TcpClient()
    Try
        tcpClient.Connect("10.xxx.xx.xx", 7000)
        TextBox1.text = TextBox1.Text + "Conneecte"
    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(e)
    End Try
    If tcpClient.Connected Then
        Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()
        Dim streamWriter As New StreamWriter(networkStream)
        Console.WriteLine("Messege {0} to {1}", data, tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint)
        streamWriter.WriteLine(data)
        streamWriter.Flush()
        tcpClient.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

And the send is successful.

And the below code is reading from another system. And the code hangs in the do while loop

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim tcpClient As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
    Try
        tcpClient.Connect("10.xxx.xx.xx", 7000)
        Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()
        If networkStream.CanWrite And networkStream.CanRead Then
            'Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("$gimme")
            'networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
            ' 'Read the NetworkStream into a byte buffer.
            Do
            Loop Until networkStream.DataAvailable
            Dim bytes(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
            networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))
            Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
            ''Label1.Text = returndata
            tcpClient.Close()
        Else
            If Not networkStream.CanRead Then
                tcpClient.Close()
            Else
                If Not networkStream.CanWrite Then
                    tcpClient.Close()
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'sLabel1.Text = "Exception Caught"
    End Try
End Sub
```

And the code hangs here in the read part

Do
                Loop Until networkStream.DataAvailable

What I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: If you writing lines, you should be reading lines. Your sender and receiver have logic that doesn't match.

Comment: Also, you're looping until the `DataAvailable` flag is set, but nothing in your code ever sets that flag. For example, you don't call `Poll`. The connection object will only change state if you perform some operation that changes its state. (Such as reading, writing, connecting, closing, polling, etcetera.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz.. I Just changed the Read method as 'Dim tcpClient As New TcpClient()
        Try
            tcpClient.Connect("10.230.10.33", 7000)
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "Conneecte"
        Catch ee As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ee)
        End Try
        If tcpClient.Connected Then
            Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()
            Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(networkStream)
            Dim str As String = reader.ReadLine()
            reader.Close()
            tcpClient.Close()
        End If'    and it fail to read

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following code it seems like your code logic is flawed.

```
' Examples for CanRead, Read, and DataAvailable.
' Check to see if this NetworkStream is readable.
If myNetworkStream.CanRead Then
   Dim myReadBuffer(1024) As Byte
       Dim myCompleteMessage As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
   Dim numberOfBytesRead As Integer = 0

   ' Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size.
   Do
      numberOfBytesRead = myNetworkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length)
           myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead))
   Loop While myNetworkStream.DataAvailable

   ' Print out the received message to the console.
       Console.WriteLine(("You received the following message : " + myCompleteMessage.ToString()))
Else
   Console.WriteLine("Sorry.  You cannot read from this NetworkStream.")
End If
```

I suggest you think about this a little longer [NetworkStream.DataAvailable Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes. The can read property is true but the system hangs at .Read method and message sent is "Test message"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no known way to read all the bytes immediately, without blocking read().
For reading a line in the way of **inputstream.ReadLine()** it's probably better to read character by character until end-of-line character is read:

```
Function readln(ByRef inputstream as Stream) as String
 Dim r as String = ""
 do
  Dim c as Char = Chr(inputstream.Read())
  If c = vbCr Then Exit loop    'vbCr or vbLf depending on application'
  r += c
 loop
 Return r
End Function
```

Not nice but functional. And doesn't eat up CPU performance when data arrives slowly or late. **inputstream.Read()** blocks for you until a character is available.